# Deterministic navigation of c++ class tags in VIM. ctags doesn't work well

Tags: c++, vim, clang, vim-plugin

Currently, to navigate `a.run()` tag, I put the cursor on `run` and press `g]`, which opens a window with enumerated list of tags for all files that have `run()`. I have to manually find an option that corresponds to `run()` in `A` class. I'd like vim to find that association for me.

It seems that clang has this type of capabilities. it works pretty well with auto-completion (clang_complete).

Is there a plug-in that has this functionality? or how do people go around it?

Comment: i asked this question at SU http://superuser.com/questions/406292/deterministic-navigation-of-c-class-tags-in-vim-ctags-doesnt-work-well, there were suggestions to move the questions here.

Comment: So what you want is accurate name resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the answer you received on superuser and I think that clang_indexer really fits your needs.

The only resources I've found are [the project page on github](https://github.com/exclipy/clang_indexer) and [this blog post](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2011/10/vim-plugin-for-navigating-c-with.html).

The plugin looks promising, but as the author says, it is at an early stage and has sharp edges.

If you try it, let us know something about it, I'm curious (I'll eventually try it myself later).

Comment: same here, indexer looks promising but it's in the early stage and there is not much info